# How to control a Python GUI via HTTP API

Tags: python, user-interface, flask, tkinter, python-multithreading

I want a Python program that implements an HTTP API (e.g. using Flask) on which it can receive messages to show various windows on the screen (e.g. using tkinter).

What is a good way of structuring such a program? I believe I will need two separate threads: one for drawing the tkinter windows and one for listening for HTTP requests.

say, I want to send an http request to e.g. /show_window, then a window is shown and kept on screen until a request is sent to /hide_window, and the window is then closed.

I can draw the window just fine via tkinter. But if I put this in a Flask route, of course it gets stuck on window.mainloop().

```
import tkinter as tk
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/show")
def show():
    root = tk.Tk()
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.0) #For icon
    root.iconify()
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry("%sx%s" % (screen_width, screen_height))
    window.configure(background='black', cursor='none')
    window.overrideredirect(1)
    window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    close = tk.Button(window, text = "Close Window", command = lambda: root.destroy())
    close.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 0)
    window.mainloop() # app is stuck here until gui window is closed
    return "show!"

@app.route("/hide")
def hide():
    ### Code to destroy or hide the Window here.
    return "hide"
```

I am thinking I need something like two threads: One that runs Flask + one that starts up the window and then the flask thread needs to send messages to the window thread in order to show, hide, create, destroy, windows, etc. 
But I am not really sure how to do that.

Note, it is in no way a requirement to use Flask or tkinter. This is just the tools that seemed good for a simple web framework for the API and a simple way of creating GUI windows.

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed need separate threads.

Here's an approach that's worked for me. It involves starting the Flask app in a separate thread, and then using something like `threading.Event` to communicate with the foreground GUI thread, or `threading.Lock` to control access to shared data structures.

Starting a Flask app in a thread is straightforward, and looks something like

```
import threading
import time

from yourapp import app

def webserver(shared_state):
    app.config['SHARED'] = shared_state
    # It isn't safe to use the reloader in a thread
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, use_reloader=False)

def main():
    shared_state = SharedState()
    ui_thread = threading.Thread(target=webserver, args=(shared_state,))
    ui_thread.start()

    while shared_state.running():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if shared_state.button_clicked():
            # do your Tk popup here
    ui_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(This is the 'spin lock' approach. Check into `threading.Event` for a different approach.)

The interesting bit is the shared state object, which uses a threading lock to serialize access to shared data (a click counter, in this example)

```
class SharedState:
    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self._running = True
        self._click_count = 0
    def record_click(self):
        # this gets called from the Flask thread to record a click
        with self._lock:
            self._click_count += 1
    def clicked(self):
        # this gets called from the GUI thread to 'get' a click
        with self._lock:
            if self._click_count > 0:
                self._click_count -= 1
                return True
            return False
    def stop(self):
        # called from either side to stop running
        with self._lock:
            self._running = False
```

The Flask side (in `yourapp.py`) does something like

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        app.config['SHARED'].record_click()
    return render_response('index.html')
```

Stopping the app from the Flask side is a bit trickier than just calling `.stop()` on the shared control. See [here](https://github.com/davewsmith/lapse/blob/master/ui/views.py#L52) for the code to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice which I tried following.  (my attempt is here: http://paste.yt/p8122.html) While I do think that the SharedState works as intended, it still seems that I am not able to actually close the window from flask. What happens is that it does seem to open the window when shared_state.visible is True. However, if I then hit the flask page again to toggle visibility, nothing seems to change. Window is not closed. I guess the main thread is stuck on "window.mainloop()". Not sure how to kick it out of that from the flask thread?