# Run while loop as background process in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, process

I'm looking to run a web server that reads a stream on `sys.stdin`. That reading needs to happen continuously, e.g. in a while loop.

However, I'm also looking to run a Flask server that listens for requests to `/data` and sends the last bit of data read from `sys.stdin` to the requesting agent.

So far I've found that my while loop is halting the execution of my app, which makes absolute sense. Here's my setup:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import sys

# state
frames = []
frame = []

while True:
  l = sys.stdin.readline()
  if 'end_frame' in l:
    frames = [frame] + frames
    frame = []
  elif l.rstrip('\n'):
    frame.append(l.rstrip('\n'))

# app
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/frames')
def get_frames():
  return jsonify(frames)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050)
```

Is there a way to run that `while` loop as a background process so as to free up the flask route listeners? Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432430/how-to-control-a-python-gui-via-http-api/55434731#55434731 will give you much of what you need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

I have a little file `publisher.py` that reads from a port on a given host (though it could just as well read from sys.stdin using the code above) in a while loop. When it composes a `frame`, it publishes that frame to a redis datastore.

Then, inside my Flask route listener `/frame`, I just ping the redis data store and then `jsonify` the result. In that way my publisher and server work together to provide data to the client as it comes in...

**publisher.py**:

```py
import sys, socket, redis, json

# config
stream = {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 6000} # streaming data host / port
r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379) # redis instance host / port

# consume data from a host+port and publish to redis on localhost
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((socket.gethostbyname(stream['host']), stream['port'])) # host, port

# consume data
frame = [] # initialize the container obj that will hold all frame data
while True:
  data = client.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
  for l in data.split('\n'):
    if 'end_frame' in l:
      d = {i.split(':')[0]: i.split(':')[1] for i in frame if ':' in i}
      r.set('frame', json.dumps(d))
      frame = []
      print(' * published frame', d.get('frame_number', ''))
    elif l.rstrip('\n'):
      frame.append(l.rstrip('\n'))
```

**server.py**:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import redis, sys, os, json

# app
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

# redis
r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379) # redis instance host / port

# route listeners
@app.route('/api/frame')
def get_frame():
  frame = json.loads(r.get('frame').decode('utf8'))
  return jsonify(frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into something like BackgroundScheduler. It runs tasks in the background as separate threads without stalling the flask listener.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
...
...
def readlines():
  l = sys.stdin.readline()
  if 'end_frame' in l:
    frames = [frame] + frames
    frame = []
  elif l.rstrip('\n'):
    frame.append(l.rstrip('\n'))

with app.app_context():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(readlines, 'interval', seconds=10)
    scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try running it in a thread

```
import threading
x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(index,))
threads.append(x)
x.start()
```

for the thread function, define your while loop in it

Comment: Hmm, seems interesting but I'm not connecting the wires. What am I missing? https://gist.github.com/duhaime/cc3afe4b9e4c2abcb3c1cd736ca5c511

Comment: The last two lines, you need to append x to threads and then start it

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an example? This seems not to work: https://gist.github.com/duhaime/cc3afe4b9e4c2abcb3c1cd736ca5c511